# Visualforce re-render and Angular

Tags: angular, visualforce, rerender

I have a Visualforce page which is using Angular app and controller to fetch and show data.

It works fine when I load the page the first time. But after that, if I re-render that page, the angular controller does not get initialized, and due to this, the page is not displaying anything.

Has anyone faced such issue?

Here Visualforce re-render can be thought as AJAX rerender of part of the page also.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Put your vfp and the angular code here. Then it will easy to understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this problem by initializing angular using bootstrap, like shown below:

```
$('#orderContent').ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap($('#orderContent'), ['OrderSummary']);
    angScope.getOrderSummaries();
    angScope.$apply();
});
```

Hope this helps others.